# How to plot scatterplot using matplotlib from arrays (using strings)? Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have been trying to plot a 3D scatterplot from a pandas array (I have tried to convert the data over to numpy arrays and strings to put into the system). However, the error `ValueError: s must be a scalar, or float array-like with the same size as x and y` keeps popping up. My data for Patient ID is in the format of EMR-001, EMR-002 etc after blanking it out. My data for Discharge Date is converted to become a string of numbers like 20200120. My data for Diagnosis Code is a mix of characters like 001 or 10B.

I have also tried to look online at some of the other examples but have not been able to identify any areas. Could I seek your advice for anything I missed out or code I can input?

I'm using Python 3.9, UTF-8. Thank you in advanced!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#importing csv data via pd
A = pd.read_csv('input.csv') #import file for current master list
Diagnosis_Des = A["Diagnosis Code"]
Discharge_Date = A["Discharge Date"]
Patient_ID = A["Patient ID"]
B = Diagnosis_Des.to_numpy()
#B1 = np.array2string(B)
#print(B.shape)
C = Discharge_Date.to_numpy() #need to change to data format
#C1 = np.array2string(C)
#print(C1)
D = Patient_ID.to_numpy()
#D1 = np.array2string(D)
#print(D.shape)

from matplotlib import pyplot
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

sequence_containing_x_vals = D
sequence_containing_y_vals = B
print(type(sequence_containing_y_vals))
sequence_containing_z_vals = C
print(type(sequence_containing_z_vals))

plt.scatter(sequence_containing_x_vals, sequence_containing_y_vals, sequence_containing_z_vals)
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: If you are doing a scatter plot you need to have the axis be something that fits along the numerics on the x,y and z axis. I imagine that you want to visualize the data somehow? Would it work to make a dictionary that associates to each string ID a numerical value for B and D? Otherwise the placement of the codes along the axis are undefined.

Comment: Yup, tks! I find a way to append the str words via len